# C++ Is there any way to discard multiple lines of std::cin input

Tags: c++, linux, cin

I'm working on a two player TCP Game that runs in the terminal. 
During the opponent's turn, the player is able to write whatever he wants in std::cin. After the turn ends that buffered information is sent to game which is what I would like to avoid.

```
Player 2's Turn
unwanted-line1
unwanted-line2
unwanted-line3
```

resulting in:

```
Player 1's turn
> unwanted-line 1
```

I've tried to use `std::ignore(<std::streamsize>::max())` but it just stops the program.

I got the recommendation of using `putback(char-that-can't-be-written)` and doing `std::ignore()` until that same char, although it didn't work because putback puts the char on the start of the buffer

Sleep can be used to reproduce the example

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string>
    #include <limits>

    int main(){
        usleep(10000000);
        std::cout << "stopped sleeping" << std::endl;

        if(std::cin.putback(27)){
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numericlimits<std::streamsize>::max(), 27);
        }

        std::string input;
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
        std::cout << "input: " << input;

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: There are ways to solve this but the fundamental issue is that C++ IO streams are not designed for, and work badly with, interactive input. You should use a library such as [libedit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libedit/) for your input instead.